# I need help about .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect esample.com/moving/city/id to esample.com/new/moving/city/id silently (Means url in Brower remains esample.com/moving/city/id) by suing .htaccess but how ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please do clearly post your url details in CODE TAGS from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite(for looking wise clarity its advised to use CODE TAGS on forum)? Also please do mention if these are going to be always same urls or is there any dynamic part there in urls(eg--> Is it always going to be same keywords mentioned `moving/city/id` OR it could be any path/keywords there?)? Kindly do edit your question with more clear details for better understanding of it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a single internal rewrite, so you need to implement a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?moving/city/(.+)$ /new/moving/city/$1 [QSA,END]
```

This would be a similar approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(moving/city/.+)$ /new/$1 [QSA,END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be enabled and activated for the requested location (host). And also the interpretation of distributed configuration files (".htaccess") needs to be enabled first if you want to use those instead of implementing such rules in the actual http server's host configuration (which you should prefer...).

If you can be more specific about what characters can actually occur within such a "cidy id" (for example only digits or only letters) then the rule could be more specific in that.

In general it is a very good idea to take a look into the documentation of the tool one plans to use, here the rewriting module of the apache http server:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
In there you will find the explanations for the `RewriteRule` directive. As typical for OpenSource software the documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

---

UPDATE:

Considering your comment to this answer it appears that what you actually ask for is a rewrite which has as *two* variable components in the request path: city name *and* some numeric id. I *assume* that the first components ("moving" in your question, now suddenly "demenagement" in your comment, is a fixed string, so I leave that as is...

Here is a variant that should implement this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?moving/(\w+)/(\d+)$ /new/moving/$1/$2 [QSA,END]
```

In case you also allow for white spaces in the city name things become a bit more complex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?moving/([a-z\s]+)/(\d+)$ /new/moving/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,END]
```

Comment: I have .htaccess below

Comment: not working for me by allopage.com/demenagement/Wattignies/2313 a want to access allopage.com/new/demenagement/Wattignies/2313.  "Wattignies/2313" first parameter is always alphabet and second interger . I try RewriteRule ^/?demenagement/(.+)$/(.+)$ /new/demenagement/$1/$1 [QSA,END]

Comment: OK, this is why questions should be _precise_ in what they actually ask :-) I made an UPDATE to the answer.